# apt-get has got broken

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have acidently removed some libraries from system and now I does not install or remove any package. Error shown in Software center and in terminal is

```
installArchives() failed: Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory a /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at/usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at/usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
Error in function:
```

When using `apt-get install anyPackage` and `apt-get install -f anyPackage` i get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
cups : Depends: libc-bin (>= 2.13) E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f
```

Comment: what happens if you type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in the terminal? (The commands only update your software if they work) If that works try `sudo apt-get install htop` (small system monitor program, to test if apt-get work.)

Comment: it produce this error. I have also tried using -f it produce same error as given above.
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     cups : Depends: libc-bin (>= 2.13)
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: Open the terminal and run the following the following command: `sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get install -f libc-bin`. I don't think it will fix everything, but you may get a new error message that will tell you more about what packages are missing.

Comment: none of these worked

Comment: well, what happened?

Comment: I have accidently removed a system package due to which this is broken

Answer (score -1):

## May problem has been sesolved. I have installed the conflicting package.

### **Solution**

Download and extract the package manually

```
apt-get download libc-bin
dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb unpackdir/
```

Copy the file to your system

```
sudo cp unpackdir/sbin/ldconfig /sbin/
```

Make sure the package and package system is in a good state.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**for original source click** [**here**](http://samonesoznanie.blogspot.com/2014/09/debian-7-cant-exec-locale-no-such-file.html)!

Comment: seriously why is this community wiki? it's perfectly fine to answer your own question...